# Watermark a document when the document is uploaded

Tags: 2010, workflow

I want to add a functionality of adding a watermark using itextSharp library to the pdf document that is being added to the library. For this I created an event listener that is triggered when item is being added. The code is as follows :

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace ProjectPrac.WatermarkOnUpload
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class WatermarkOnUpload : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An item was added.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            var file = properties.ListItem.File;
            // open the file either as a Byte array 
            // Byte[] content = file.OpenBinary();
            // OR a Stream
            Stream content = file.OpenBinaryStream();

            string watermarkedFile = "Watermarked.pdf";
            // Creating watermark on a separate layer
            // Creating iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader object to read the Existing PDF Document
            PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(content);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(watermarkedFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            // Creating iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper object to write Data from iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader object to FileStream object
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader1, content))
            {
                // Getting total number of pages of the Existing Document
                int pageCount = reader1.NumberOfPages;

                // Create New Layer for Watermark
                PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("WatermarkLayer", stamper.Writer);
                // Loop through each Page
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                    // Getting the Page Size
                    Rectangle rect = reader1.GetPageSize(i);

                    // Get the ContentByte object
                    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);

                    // Tell the cb that the next commands should be "bound" to this new layer
                    cb.BeginLayer(layer);
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(
                      BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 50);

                    PdfGState gState = new PdfGState();
                    gState.FillOpacity = 0.25f;
                    cb.SetGState(gState);

                    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                    cb.BeginText();
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Confidential", rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2, 45f);
                    cb.EndText();

                    // Close the layer
                    cb.EndLayer();
                }


                // apply your watermark, then save the Byte[] / Stream
                file.SaveBinary(content);

            }


        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how to add the path without hardcoding it here :

```
PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Hello.pdf");      //THE RELATIVE PATH
```

And then uploading the watermarked document to the library and not the original pdf.
I know that it can also be done through workflow but I am pretty new to sharepoint. So if at all you have an answer that has workflow in it please give  the link that explains the workflow for automating the pdf watermarking.

Comment: although it won't fix your issue, you can remove this line `base.ItemAdded(properties);` as it is not needed. Also, what's the point of instantiating a `FileStream fs` object, when you don't use it anywhere in the code that follows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use the `ItemAdded` event, instead of the `ItemAdding`, as in the latter you don't have access yet to the SPFile object.

That said, here is how to get hold of the file that was added to the library:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
  var file = properties.ListItem.File;
  // open the file either as a Byte array 
  Byte[] content = file.OpenBinary();
  // OR a Stream
  Stream content = file.OpenBinaryStream();

  // apply your watermark, then save the Byte[] / Stream
  file.SaveBinary(content);
}
```

Comment: How do I write the file location in the code : PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Hello.pdf")   instead of c:\\users\\....................

Comment: You **don't** need the file path! PdfReader has an overload with a byte[] as parameter. Use that

Comment: I am updating the code I have given here. It is not able to watermark the document

Comment: My knowledge of iTextSharp is limited, but the problem almost surely lies on the code related to it

Comment: I debugged it and the event receiver is not getting triggered. I don't know why

Comment: Debuggin an event receiver, if you don't know how to do it, can be a nightmare. Try googling or see this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38297/debugging-sandboxed-itemupdated-event-receiver-breakpoints-not-hit